# Routing to and from wired net, OSX

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, routing

I have a Mac, it's connected to the internet by Wifi on a 192.168.1.* network where .1 is the default gatway.

I wanted to play with some old hardware that doesn't have wifi so I connected a switch to my ethernet port on the Mac and gave that port ip 192.168.2.2 255.255.255.0 and no default gateway. The switch is a managed HP Procure, I gave it ip, 192.168.2.1, same mask and 192.168.2.2 as default gateway.

From my Mac I can now access Internet and the whole 192.168.1.* network.
I can also talk to 192.168.2.1 (the switch) and .2 (my self).

The problem is that I can't get the 192.168.2.1 (the switch) to talk to anything on 192.168.1.1 or the internet.

I have tried different versions of `route add` on the mac but can't get anything to work, host not reachable, target did not respond etc... I realize putting the switch into the Wifi router and running everything on 192.168.1.* would fix everything but that's not an option.

Here are the relevant lines from netstat -rn, this is all default stuff not added by me.

```
192.168.2          link#8             UCS             2        0     en0      !
192.168.2.1        0:14:c2:9a:ff:40   UHLWI           0       44     en0   1186
192.168.2.2/32     link#8             UCS             1        0     en0      !
192.168.2.255      ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI          0        5     en0      !
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do forwarding, [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/97117/how-do-i-enable-ip-forwarding-in-macos-x) might help you